# How to create an infinitely long line

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, scene

Whats is the best way of creating a line (QGraphicsLineItem) which starts at some point on the scene and continues to infinity at some angle.

The way I presently do this is by calculating were the line intersects the view and drawing the line segment.

Is there a better way?

Could I for example set the lines length to some massive number?

Comment: "Could I for example set the lines length to some massive number?" - that's what I would do. Even if the number is very large, Qt should be able to optimize that easily for a single line.

Comment: Do you want to be the graphics item that large or just draw it infinitely? For the latter one, you could draw it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You could define its paint() and shape() functions so they always use all the space available and needed inside the scene, i.e. inside the visible part of qgraphicsview.

Guidelines:

- Examine mapping functions for qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene and
  qgraphicsitem (mapToScene, mapToItem, mapToView or something like that)
- Define your shape() and paint() functions as if your
  line is exactly long all over the view (by using the mapping functions above)

So, how ever the user moves his view, repaint will examine the space used by qgraphicsview and draw exactly that long. The illusion is created that the line goes on-and-on.